# SL5 out-of-browser app, controlling the containing window

Tags: silverlight-5.0, out-of-browser

In SL5 you can create multiple windows.  This package allows you to use a window modally, and not have it constrained by the parent window:  http://slmultiwindow.codeplex.com/

Is there any way to control the containing window's background or opacity?  I'd like to animate the appearance and disappearance of the modal window; while I can control the window content via storyboard, the containing window's white background sort of ruins the effect...

Any ideas would be appreciated for how to control the appearance of the containing window...

Answer (score 1):

I Think You Should Try this Way..........

1 . Click On Sliverlight Project

2 . Select Properties option

3 . Select First tab option Like Silverlight

4 . Click On Out-Of-Browser setting Option

5 . Set the window size, window title or window position etc......

Comment: Color and opacity aren't available as options.  I have since learned that P/Invoke could be used, but that won't work on the Mac (where my SL app is expected to run).